# Viewing object returned from realm.object()

Tags: react-native, realm

I added data to a realm using

```
realm.write(() => {
    for (const player in players) {
      realm.create('Player', {
        id: player.id,
        firstname: player.firstname,
        lastname: player.lastname,   
      });
    }
  });
```

players is a JSON array.

```
[
  {
    "id": 9687,
    "firstname": "Nyeem",
    "lastname": "Young",
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "firstname": "Jason",
    "lastname": "Holder",
  }]
```

I was able to confirm that the data was entered successfully by using

```
realmPlayers = realm.objects('Player');
console.log(`There are ${realmPlayers.length} players`); // 99
```

However when I try to get all the players

```
console.log(realmPlayers)
```

I get the error

```
[TypeError: item.toJSON is not a f
unction. (In 'item.toJSON(index.toString(), cache)', 'item.toJSON' is undefined)]
```

`console.log(JSON.stringify(realmPlayers));` gives the same error.

`console.log(realmPlayers[0]); returns {}`

Trying to use a filter

```
realm.objects('Player').filtered('lastname = Young');
```

I get the error

```
Failed to open the realm 'Player' has no property: 'Young'
```

If I have items in the database why can't I access it. Ultimately what I want to do is to get all the items in the database and pass the result to a FlatList component in React Native..

How can I get the data and possible visualize it via the command line?

Comment: Not sure the question is clear. Your code creates Realm objects from the fields in your JSON data `realm.create('Player'` using `player.id`, `player.firstName` and `player.lastName`. So... the data is no longer JSON, it's Realm, and you need to use Realm constructs to access those Realm objects. So... what's the question?

Comment: What are those Realm constructs you speak off. From the documentation realm.objects('Player'); should return all the players but a console.log of that command returns nothing. That is my question. How can I retrieve all the items to display in either in console.log or visually in the app.

Comment: *should return all the players* - it does, as a Results object which has no `.toJSON` function. From the [Realm Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/read-and-write-data/#std-label-react-native-read-operations) - *Query operations return a collection of Realm objects that match the query as a Realm.Results object.* and then the definition is: [Realm.Results](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/latest/Realm.Results.html). A typical use is `const players = realm.objects(“Player”);` and `console.log('all players: ${players.map((player) => player.firstname)}');`

Comment: Thanks @Jay I'll give this a try later on a different branch, I have moved on to a different local storage library, which had better examples to back up the API.